# Drupal Rules: How do I check if node is updated via edit form or via VBO?

Tags: rules, views, actions

I'm trying to build a reaction rule that fires on the event `After updating existing content`, but with the condition to only run after the node has been manually updated using the node edit form, *not* as part of a Views Bulk Operation action that updates nodes.
My issue is I can't find a condition that achieves this.

Does anybody have an idea? Thanks for thinking along :-)

Comment: Not sure there's anything off-the-shelf that would do this. Can you write PHP code?

Comment: I guess a custom condition (PHP) would be a possibility, but I wouldn't really know what to compare/check for.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is slightly experimental as I have done something similar but not precisely the same. You may need to do further work, but here's the outline which will require a custom module that uses Entity API. What it does is create a custom node property which says where it was updated from:

1. Implement hook_node_submit() to check which form the node update has been submitted from and if it's a node_edit, add a custom member item to the node object, eg `$node->is_node_edit = TRUE;`
2. Implement [hook_entity_property_info_alter()](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!entity!entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_property_info_alter/7) to add a custom property to the node entity type corresponding to the custom member as above.
3. Implement the getter callback you declared in that hook to be something like:

   function mymodule_node_update_from_edit($data, array $options, $name, $type, $info) {
    $node = $data;
    return (boolean)@$node->is_node_edit;
   }

You can then check the value of the property in a Rules condition.